# Множественный выбор в QComboBox

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qcombobox, qstandarditemmodel

Есть довольно простой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QApplication
import sys


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel("", self)
        self.label.move(20, 50)

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem("option 1")
        combo.addItem("option 2")
        combo.addItem("option 3")
        combo.move(10, 10)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как сделать множественный выбор `QComboBox`? 
А потом получать список выбранных элементов по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


LastStateRole = Qt.UserRole + 1000

def checkable_combox(combo, options):
    model = QStandardItemModel(len(options), 1)
    for i, area in enumerate(options):
        item = QStandardItem(area)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i, 0, item)
    combo.setModel(model)
    

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        usecase_type = ["сделать выбор", "option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
        checkable_combox(self.combo, usecase_type)
        self.combo.model().itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Button") 
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        
    def btn_clicked(self):
        self.label.clear()
        for i in range(self.combo.model().rowCount()):
            item = self.combo.model().item(i, 0)
            checked = item.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
            if checked and (item.text() != "сделать выбор"):
                self.label.setText(f'{self.label.text()}\n{item.text()}: checked')

    @pyqtSlot("QStandardItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        last_state = item.data(LastStateRole)
        current_state = item.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        if last_state != current_state:
            item.model().blockSignals(True)
            item.setData(current_state, LastStateRole)
            item.model().blockSignals(False)
            #print(f'{item.text()}: {current_state}' )        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(300, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]